Input Variable Error in Prompt When Using Example Selector in Langchain
I'm new to using LangChain and currently experimenting with the SemanticSimilarityExampleSelector to avoiding adding unnecessary examples in the prompt. However, I've encountered an issue when trying to integrate an ExampleSelector with a ChatPromptTemplate.
Here’s what I’m trying to achieve:
I want to use ExampleSelector within ChatPromptTemplate to dynamically select relevant examples based on the input.
The implementation works fine without the ExampleSelector, but when I add the selector, I encounter the following error:
Error Message:
Error in prompt: 'input_text'. It probably throws error before final prompt as It does not get printed.
Here is the code:
def extract_information(input_text, examples, model):
try:
active_model = LLMManager.get_instance(model=model)
print(f"Examples={examples}")
embedding = FastEmbedEmbeddings()
example_selector = SemanticSimilarityExampleSelector.from_examples(
examples,
embedding,
FAISS,
k=4
)
few_shot_prompt = FewShotChatMessagePromptTemplate(
example_selector=example_selector,
example_prompt=ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages(
[("human", "{input}"), ("ai", "{output}")]
)
)
print(f"loaded model")
base_prompt=f"""Role: You are a helpful assistant
Input Text: "{input_text}"\n,
output: """

    final_prompt = (
            SystemMessagePromptTemplate.from_template(
                base_prompt
            )
            + few_shot_prompt
            + HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{input_text}")
        )
    print(f"final prompt={final_prompt.format()}")
    chain = final_prompt | active_model
    result = chain.invoke({"input_text": input_text})
    print(f"result={result}")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error in prompt:{e}")
    return None

System Info
linux
langchain-python
latest langchain package`
langchain documentation, github page, code review
